# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'($find smartcar)/urdf/smartc

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done as the tutorials of ROS in the part of 'UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch' but the still gets the error

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'($find smartcar)/urdf/smartc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232718/ioerror:-%5Berrno-2%5D-no-such-file-or-directory:-u%27($find-smartcar)/urdf/smartc/) by [jxbjnba](https://answers.ros.org/users/26685/jxbjnba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it's just a typo in the launch file. Try: `"$(find smartcar)/urdf/smartc"` (Notice how the dollar sign, `$`, should come before the parentheses.)

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0